# Dynamic Chart Shows no data MSCHART, only white chart appears

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, mschart

Here is the Problem. 
I need to create multiple charts(number is not known previously). So, I am generating dynamic Chart. The problem is, chart appears but shows no data. It is just a blank white space.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Chart demo = new Chart();
    demo.Location = new Point(0, 0);
    demo.Size=new Size(this.Width,this.Height);
    demo.Series.Add("check");
    DataPoint dp1 = new DataPoint(1, 1);
    DataPoint dp2 = new DataPoint(2, 2);
    DataPoint dp3 = new DataPoint(3, 3);
    demo.Series["check"].Points.Add(dp1);
    demo.Series["check"].Points.Add(dp2);
    demo.Series["check"].Points.Add(dp3);
    this.Controls.Add(demo);
    demo.BringToFront();
    demo.Visible = true;
}
```

Output is just a white chart with nothing on it.

Comment: why don't you try using ASP Chart controls?

Comment: [ASP Chart Control](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/24/new-asp-net-charting-control-lt-asp-chart-runat-quot-server-quot-gt.aspx)

Comment: i have to use winform in my project

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a chart area. Just add this line in your code.

```
demo.ChartAreas.Add("newchartarea");
```

Comment: precise and short answer. cant vote up requires 15 reputation. Thanks

Comment: @user2594183 : But you could and should have accepted the answer!